# Teamcity ftp Upload error connection

Tags: ftp, teamcity

I am trying to build and deploy my project in team city. For upload to ftp server using plugin [Ftp Upload](http://teamcityrunners.codeplex.com/).

settings deploy step:

- Folder to upload: `snab`
- FTP address: `ftp://10.5.0.250`
- Remote folder: `test`
- user name: `anonymous`

  When established connection to ftp server `error: invalid ipv6 address` [build log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0ROV.png). Why using ipv6 address? and how to switch ipv4 address?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the plugin you are using is no longer maintained (last update is in 2012). Please try the alternative plugin: confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TW/Deployer+plugin

Answer (score 0):

**Change FTP Service Status**

Command to check status list:

- inetadm

or specificly;

- svcs ftp

If your status is **offline** or **disabled**, you must change your status to enable. To do that:

1. svcadm -v enable network/ftp
2. svcadm refresh svc:/network/ftp:default
3. svcadm restart svc:/network/ftp:default

Check your status again:

- svcs ftp